# How to slow down full disk scan process?

Tags: c#, file, search, io

I'm developing an application that once for a while (mostly after reboot) has to search entire drive to check if files with the given extensions have changed since last reboot.

At first everything seemed to be working as expected but after a while it turned out that not for all users. Some of them started complaining that their computers are almost frozen during first couple minutes after reboot. The reason is huge disk activity (I\O).

So I have an unusual question how to slow down the full scan process?
I’m using below code. Should I use Sleep method or change the logic?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string rootFolderPath, Regex fileSearchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    Queue<string> pending = new Queue<string>();
    pending.Enqueue(rootFolderPath);
    IEnumerable<string> tmp;

    while (pending.Count > 0)
    {
        rootFolderPath = pending.Dequeue();

        tmp = EnumerateFiles(rootFolderPath, searchOpt)
              .Where(file => fileSearchPattern.IsMatch(
                  Path.GetExtension(file)
              ));

        foreach (string file in tmp)
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string rootFolderPath, string directoryName, Regex directorySearchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    foreach (string directory in EnumerateDirectories(rootFolderPath, directoryName, searchOpt)
                                .Where(d => directorySearchPattern.IsMatch(d + @"\")))
    {
        yield return directory;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path,  SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    try
    {
        var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            dirFiles = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                                .SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchOpt));
        }
        return dirFiles.Concat(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path));
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    try
    {
        var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            directories = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory)
                .SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
        }
        return directories.Concat(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory));
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Reboot of the PC or of your app?

Comment: And is there a specific reason for all this DIY recursion code instead of just passing AllDirectories to Directory.EnumerateFiles() ?

Comment: When I try to use only Directory.EnumerateFiles() I receive UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: maybe you should have another approach e.g. have a service that subscribes to file changes see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx that way you don't need to bother the user at reboot, we users are all not so fond of waiting

Comment: and not so fond of anything happening at reboot and/or startup.

Comment: Why not add some `Thread.Sleep(x)` in your code that does the `foreach`?

Comment: I tried using Thread.Sleep(100) but then for my drive (300GB) it takes more then 1 hour to scan full disk.

Comment: _When I try to use only Directory.EnumerateFiles() I receive UnauthorizedAccessException_ Catch and ignore it! It comes from the restricted folders..

Comment: Why not keep a counter for how many operations you have done, and every x operations you do a `Thread.Sleep(x)` e.g. `if(counter % 100 == 0) Thread.Sleep(100)`. And in your `foreach`, you increment counter.

Comment: I cannot ignore exception for Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories) because program stops processing and no file is returned

Comment: The Thread.Sleep() at interval does seem to be the solution, experiment with the values. I would estimate a short Sleep (like 10 ms) every 100 or 1000 files or so. But part of what goes on is out of your control, it is happening in deep down in the OS.

Answer (score 4):

First thing I would do is delay the start of this operation. OS startup already does *a lot* of I/O work, so having a very I/O intensive process running at the same time is probably not a good idea. Perhaps sleep for 1 or 2 minutes before you start scanning the disk.

Then, during the scan process, you can slow it down by adding a `Sleep` every N iterations, as suggested by Michal in the comments.

Another option, a bit more complex, would be to analyze the NTFS journal to see which files have changed. Note that it requires admin privileges, though, so your process would have to run elevated (you could make it a service so that it doesn't need UAC confirmation every time).

Answer (score 0):

Make the scan algorithm poll a [`PauseToken`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cellfish/archive/2013/01/31/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-pausetoken.aspx) frequently. Make a timer signal the token for 100ms every 1000ms. That gives the computer 10% idle time.

This was the simple variant. A better variant would be to make due without the timer but that requires calculating with time durations which is harder.